# How to set a default value for a datetime column to record creation time in a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider the table creation script below:

```
create_table :foo do |t|
  t.datetime :starts_at, :null => false
end
```

Is it's possible to set the default value as the current time?

I am trying to find a DB independent equivalent in rails for the SQL column definitions given below:

**Oracle Syntax**

```
start_at DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE()
```

**MySQL Syntax**

```
start_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

OR

```
start_at DATETIME DEFAULT NOW()
```

Answer (score 198, accepted):

This is supported now in Rails 5.

Here is a sample migration:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.datetime :modified_at, default: -> { 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' }
      t.timestamps
    end
  end 
end
```

See discussion at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27077 and answer there by prathamesh-sonpatki

Comment: Great answer. Purely as an aside, be aware that in Postgres `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will be the time of the start of the current transaction, so multiple records created in the same transaction will get that same value. If you want the actual current time the statement executes (ignoring transaction context), check out `CLOCK_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: I added something like this:
`add_column :table_name, :start_date, :datetime, default: -> { 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' }` and this is what it loooks like in the schema.rb
`t.datetime "start_date", default: -> { "now()" }` But when I created new record, it's not not being populated. Any idea why?

Comment: @SandipSubedi same for me. On rails 5.2.3.

Comment: @courtsimas you need to do `post.reload` to get those values. It's explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804787/rails-5-2-and-active-record-migration-with-current-timestamp

Comment: @SandipSubedi I realized that 5 minutes after my comment. Just like with uuid generation. Thanks!

Comment: @SandipSubedi any idea why `default: -> { "now()" }` is printed on the schema instead of `default: -> { 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' }` ?

Comment: Haven't realized the difference. But on my `schema.rb` it get changed depending on who is running. And it hasn't been an issue for me.

Comment: @SandipSubedi I'm facing a similar situation. Nothing is breaking, I suspect it's a postgres version thing.

Answer (score 125):

You can add a function in a model like this:

```
  before_create :set_foo_to_now
  def set_foo_to_now
    self.foo = Time.now
  end
```

So that the model will set the current time in the model.

You can also place some sql code in the migration for setting the default value at the database level, something like:

```
execute 'alter table foo alter column starts_at set default now()'
```

Setting something like this:

```
create_table :foo do |t|
  t.datetime :starts_at, :null => false, :default => Time.now
end
```

causes executing the Time.now function during migrating so then the table in database is created like this:

```
create table foo ( starts_at timestamp not null default '2009-01-01 00:00:00');
```

but I think that it is not what you want.

Comment: Currently I am setting the value in the :before_create callback.<br>
I was looking for some type of AR magic here. I spent some time looking at the Rails code, but I didn't find any solution. I thought I will ask around to see if there are any alternatives.

Comment: I would suggest doing it with a callback on before_create.

Comment: I don't want to alter the DB table as I want to keep my code DB neutral. I was hoping that AR had some mechanism to set the default value for the Datetime field similar to created_at field.

Comment: Be careful with Time.now. Usually you want to use Time.zone.now.

Comment: Be aware that **before_create** callback runs before inserting to database but after you instantiate your object (like with `new()`). So `self.foo = Time.now` will override the value you might give to `new()`. I suggest `self.foo = Time.current unless self.foo.present?` instead.

Comment: Not that, when using the execute, this will put a line `:starts_at, :default => 'now()'` in the schema.rb. However this won't work when using `rake db:schema:dump` which will override the schema.rb with  `:starts_at, :default => '2015-05-29 09:46:33'` (or whatever the date when you launch the script)... sad....

Answer (score 16):

If you need to **change** an *existing DateTime column* in Rails 5 (rather than creating a new table as specified in other answers) so that it can take advantage of the default date capability, you can create a migration like this:

```
class MakeStartsAtDefaultDateForFoo < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_column :foos, :starts_at, :datetime, default: -> { 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' }
  end
end
```

Comment: Bad form to vote something down and not explain what issue was taken with the answer. Anybody have an idea why this was voted down? It's displaying the syntax if you wanted to change a column instead of creating one.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I'm having difficulty seeing how this answer differs from will's answer that precedes yours by one year. The question is about setting a default, and your answer has the same lambda clause.

Comment: @nurettin I get your point, but in my defense, the syntax for **creating** a new column is subtly different from **changing** an existing column. Providing that syntax for those who found this question via web search while trying to add a default to their current data model rather than creating a new model/table altogether is probably pretty helpful. No? You are assuming everybody knows they can use the same lambda for a change_column. Maybe they should realize that, but that's why I answered here--so they don't have to go anywhere else to figure that out. Cheers!

Comment: I understand why you did it, but it looks more like a comment than an answer is all I'm saying. No intention to annoy, just answering your question.

Comment: @nurettin Probably better as a comment--except for the syntax highlighting ;-) Thanks for the feedback. I'll see if anybody else concurs with another down vote.

Comment: FWIW I just now used this syntax and appreciate that for my google search and particular problem this answer helped me the most.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this being an answer rather than a comment.  Upvoted.  I think the downvoters are just reading carelessly (like most of the question closers! ;p ).

Comment: Found this useful as was looking for migrating on existing model and found this.

Answer (score 12):

> Active Record automatically timestamps create and update operations if the table has fields named `created_at`/`created_on` or `updated_at`/`updated_on`. [Source - api.rubyonrails.org](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html)

You don't need to do anything else except to have that column.

Comment: I already have those fields in my table. I need an additional field for my scheduler to hold the start date. Currently, I am using :before_create callback to set the current date. If I encounter this scenario frequently, I have to resort to writing a plugin to alter the default value handling in 'to_sql' method of ColumnDefinition class.

Answer (score 10):

I was searching for a similar solutions but I ended using https://github.com/FooBarWidget/default_value_for.

The `default_value_for` plugin allows one to define default values for ActiveRecord models in a declarative manner. For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_value_for :name, "(no name)"
  default_value_for :last_seen do
    Time.now
  end
end

u = User.new
u.name       # => "(no name)"
u.last_seen  # => Mon Sep 22 17:28:38 +0200 2008
```

Answer (score 9):

I usually do:

```
def change
  execute("
    ALTER TABLE your_table
    ALTER COLUMN your_column
    SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ")
end
```

So, your `schema.rb` is going to have something like:

```
create_table "your_table", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "your_column", default: "now()"
end
```

Comment: The downside: this solution only works when you run `rake db:migrate`, not when you load your schema file with something like `rake db:schema:load`.

Comment: This makes your schema column change to evaluated date time every migration running

Answer (score 4):

Did you know that [upserts fail unless you have a default `updated_at/created_at`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62920139/1536309)????

there is no migration flag which automatically does this, you have to manually include an options object with a `default` key

```
create_table :table_foos do |t|
  #...
  # date with timestamp
  t.datetime :last_something_at, null: false, default: -> { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" }
  
  # standard timestamps
  t.timestamps({default: -> { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" }})
end
```

Answer (score -1):

In the answer given by @szymon-lipiński (Szymon Lipiński), the execute method didn't work for me. It was throwing a MySQL syntax error.

The MySQL syntax which worked for me is this.

```
execute "ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE `column_name` `column_name` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
```

So to set the default value for a datetime column in migration script can be done as follows:

```
def up
  create_table :foo do |t|
    t.datetime :starts_at, :null => false
  end

  execute "ALTER TABLE `foo` CHANGE `starts_at` `starts_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
end
```