# The has_many :through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Example from Guide with additional property in association model

```
class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :physicians do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :patients do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :appointments do |t|
      t.belongs_to :physician, index: true
      t.belongs_to :patient, index: true
      t.datetime :appointment_date
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Model Appointment has a validation:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient

  validates :appointment_date, presence: true
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

When I add patient to physicians `some_physician.patient << some_patient` I have to define `appointment_date`. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to do it correctly?

In my opinion, you can define a method, and pass that method into `before_save` callback.

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_appointment_date

  private
  def set_appointment_date
    self.appointment_date = Time.now
  end
end
```

That's how you don't need to explicitly set the `appointment_date` each time you create a relationship. It will be automatically set for you.

**Edit:**
`before_save` will also fire if you later want to `update` your appointment object, though that is a very rare case. But it will update the `appointment_date`. For that, you can use `before_create` callback, and `appointment_date` will be touched only once in that case.

Comment: sorry, but appointment_date is property of Appointment, not Patient

Comment: So, `has_many :patients, through: :appointments` makes no sense, because I have to use only `has_many :appointments` association.

Comment: But an appointment only happens when a patient _and_ a physician both agree. And yeah you can skip `has_many :patients, through: :appointments` if you do not want keep record of how many patients are there for the appointments of a particular doctor, which obviously you wouldn't want.

Comment: @DavydovEugene something to note on that `before_save` callback, it will happen every time you save an appointment. So if you are updating an appointment for some other reason it will change the `appointment_date` to now.

Comment: @DickieBoy Well, if that is the case, you can use `before_create` callback. I leave it up to the OP, and also edit my question to reflect this. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have to define it is because `some_physician.patient << some_patient` creates an implicit appointment to link the two. An appointment is invalid if you leave `appointment_date` blank.

If you don't want an appointment, define a new relationship between `physicians` and `patients`.

Otherwise it makes sense to do something like:

```
appointment = some_physician.appointments.create(patient: some_patient, appointment_date: Time.now)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is can be achieved without `before_save` callback, Rails update `timestamps` automatically. Just create a right migration file, assume you are use `postgresql` as orm.

```
create_table :appointments do |t|
  t.belongs_to :physician, index: true
  t.belongs_to :patient, index: true
  t.timestamps :appointment_date, default: 'now()'
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

Instead `datetime` columntype use `timestamps` as `created_at` or `updated_at` with a plain sql function [`now()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html)

> Current date and time (equivalent to current_timestamp)

It's happens under the hood.

[Some references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1580847/2057388)

Comment: My question about mandatory fields in association model. It maybe other field which we have to fill before save.

Comment: @davydes i just show some feature what rails provide for your.