# Rails Upsert PG created_at issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Sorry if this has been answered before but I can't find a definite answer.

Surely someone has come across this issue when using `upsert` you need to specify every column including `created_at` and `updated_at`?

How can I not update the `created_at` timestamp when an upsert happens? I only want to insert `created_at` once.

```
a = User.upsert({
          name: ....,
          age: ....
          created_at: DateTime.now, 
          updated_at: DateTime.now
        }, unique_by: :upsert_user_index )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to provide `created_at` and `updated_at` if you had already set the `default` value i.e. `now()` in the db. It will automatically takes the current timestamp.

```
a = User.upsert({
          name: ....,
          age: ....,
          created_at: Time.now,
          updated_at:Time.now
          
        }, nil, unique_by: :upsert_user_index )
```

But if you want to insert a single record, you should use `create` or `save`. It will trigger the validations and callbacks. And if you want to skip them, you can do as well.
You should use `upsert_all` if want to insert multiple entries in single sql without callbacks and validations.

Comment: `upsert` typically does require `created_at` and `updated_at` as they typically have non-null constraints in the database.  You're right about just using create or save instead.

Answer (score 11):

Update Existing tables with defaults:

```
change_column :table_foos, :created_at, :datetime, null: false, default: -> { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" }
change_column :table_foos, :updated_at, :datetime, null: false, default: -> { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" }
```

Create NEW tables with defaults:

```
create_table :table_foos do |t|
  # date with timestamp
  t.datetime :last_something_at, null: false, default: -> { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" }
  
  # standard timestamps
  t.timestamps default: -> { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" }
end
```